# What are "parsley greens"?

Tags: parsley

I have a recipe that calls for 2 cups of "parsley greens". Is this referring to chopped parsley?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most contexts, I would assume that simply means the leaves from the herb parsley.

Depending on where your recipe originates—especially central Europe, or some Asian cultures—parsley root may also be used, so the recipe might be trying to make that clear.

I suspect, however, it really is the recipe author's idiosyncratic style.

Now, as to chopping them, that would depend on how it is used and what the rest of the recipe says.

Comment: Strictly speaking, parsley isn't an herb...

Comment: How is it not an herb?  https://www.google.com/search?q=herb+definition&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS438US438&aq=f&oq=herb+definition&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.3506j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: It's more a vegetable, or a salad green. I suspect in north America it's just a herb or garnish

Comment: In my lexicon, an *herb* is something where you only ever use the greens, whereas in my household at least, parsley is as important for the root as it is for the leaves.

Comment: Depending on how its cultivated, it can be an herb, vegetable, or spice.  As far as cooking is concerned, it should be an herb (salad is not cooking) and refer to the leafs.  The vegetable should be called parsley root the same way celery root is called and how celery doesn't refer to the root.  Another analogy: Grape refers to the fruit, not the leaves that some people cook with and not the seeds we get oil from.

Comment: Its a non-woody green leafy plant.  That's an herb :-)  Parts of it may be used as a spice or a vegetable or dried and used to thatch a hut :-)

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ So lettuce is a herb?